# How to implement a custom tab bar with Flutter that supports tapping even when tabs are outside the visible range?

Tags: flutter

[image: 1]

How to customize a tabbar like this with Flutter, and the round image could be tapped? The red rectangle is tabbar.

I have try cover a large image on middle tab but it did not work well:

```dart
//the middle tab
Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Tab(
                  text: "Bills",
                  icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
                ),
                Container(
                    child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 30.h,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.assignment,
                        size: 80.h,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

I have two questions:

1. How to add widget beyond super widget? Like the round image beyond the tabbar without the overflow error?
2. How to detect the tap only in tabbar(the red line)? I'm familiar with iOS method **hitTest** check.

Comment: you can use the GestureDetector widget. The GestureDetector widget allows you to detect gestures, such as taps, on widgets. To detect a tap on the round image, you can wrap the GestureDetector widget around the Image widget that displays the round image.

Comment: @Dhruvil How can I make the round image beyond the tabbar bound?